# Threads freezing screen

Tags: java, android, multithreading

All this is in the same class and onCreate method:

```
String arrayExtra[] = {"1"};
for(int x = 0; x < arrayExtra.length; x++){
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        try{
            final EditText etAbun = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etIsoAbunNum);
            synchronized(this){
                wait();
                allExtraiso.add(etAbun.getText().toString());
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});

Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try{
            synchronized(this){
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                final Button bNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bIsoAbunSave);
                bNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0){
                        notify();
                    }
                });
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});

thread.start();
thread2.start();
try{
    thread.join();
}catch(InterruptedException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try{
    thread2.join();
}catch(InterruptedException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

What this code should do, is create 2 threads, wait for a button click, then when the button is clicked, do notify(), then continue the remaining code. What this does is though is just freeze the screen. The for loop should not be running forever, but I am not sure.

Comment: Have you tried adding some logging? Like log when the onClick method is called, and log from within notify.

Comment: I think thread.join() is freezing the ui, however, what's the point in creating a thread that gets activated when the user click a button? Wouldn't be easier to create the thread when the user click the button?

Comment: @lelloman The thread isn't getting activated when the user clicks the button, the thread is already activated and is waiting for a click. (If I understand you correctly) The code has to work like this. Also, if thread.join() is freezing the ui, is there a way to unfreeze it?

Comment: what do you think `thread.join();` does, exactly ?

Comment: Instead of threads, try using AsyncTasks: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html They are designed with the UI thread in mind.

Comment: My point is that, maybe, you could find a more elegant solution for the problem. Are you really sure that "the code has to work like this"? Regarding the unfreezing thing, when you call `join` on a thread B from thread A, thread A will stuck on that line of code until thread B has finished, and since the ui is on thread A you don't want this.

Answer (score 1):

You are starting the separate threads and the call join() on them right away. The call join() is executed by your main thread (since you are in onCreate). What this method does is tell your current thread to wait until the other thread is finished. So your main thread gets blocked until the other thread dies.

But your threads are waiting for the user to click a button. User events are processed by the UI thread, which is currently blocked in join(). So the click is not processed, the event handler will never be called and you have a deadlock situation.

Multi-threading should be avoided whenever possible, because it adds a lot of complexity to your program and often does not add any benefits. It is necessary when doing something time consuming in android and you don't want to block the UI thread with that task.

You should probably remove the threads and find some other way to achieve what you want.

**Update**

There is actually another problem with your code, that would also prevent it from working: you are synchronizing, waiting and notifying on different objects. So the call to notify() would never reach the thread in wait() even if the click event was processed.

Comment: The way the program works is that I need to wait for a button click, then continue the code, and the only way I know to do this is by using threads, but that is popping up problems. Would you know any other way to pause the running of code until an action (click of a button) is performed?

Comment: @user154989 what is wrong with putting the code you want to execute in the button click and remove the threads

Comment: You don't need threads to do that. In order to achieve something like that, you should be using the event handler of the button (like you already do in your second thread). You have to restructure your code into several parts, one to be executed for example in onCreate right away and the other that shall be executed on button click.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be doing the major part of your work inside the Main Thread (UI thread)  I don't think you want to use join here.  A reentrant Lock with a Condition object is probably what your are looking for if you want to keep this mechanic.  with this you will be able to `await` inside you thread Object when you want to block and `signal` when the button is pushed.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html

but unless you wanted to do processing before the button was pushed, creating the thread lazily upon the action occurring might be a good approach.  AsyncTask might also be very good to look at.